# Intel Intrinsics: combine every other word from 2 registers

Tags: assembly, intel, intrinsics

I have two __m128i registers, let's call them srcA and srcB.  From that I want to get an __m128i register, let's say dst, which contains the following words (pseudo-code assuming srcA, srcB and dst are word pointers):

```
dst[0] = srcA[0];
dst[1] = srcA[1];
dst[2] = srcA[2];
dst[3] = srcA[3];
dst[4] = srcB[0];
dst[5] = srcB[1];
dst[6] = srcB[2];
dst[7] = srcB[3];
```

How can I accomplish this output using intrinsics?

Comment: So, that's what you want to get. Fine. What is the question?  Also: `__m128i` is a Microsoft C keyword, but there is no `C` tag on the question. There is, however, an `assembly` tag on the question.  So, are you looking for a solution in C, or a solution involving assembly with XMM[0-7] ?

Comment: Edited the question... I'm looking for a  solution using assembly.

Comment: Your question still mentions "intrinsics" and "__m128i" which are a C/C++ concepts, not an assembly ones. Also you should mention which Intel architecture. Presumably you mean x86, but Intel's Itanium (IA-64) compiler also supports __m128 based intrinsics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also forgot to mention which SSE level you are targeting. As such, I will use the most convenient one, SSE4.1 :)

```
dst = _mm_blend_epi16(srcA, _mm_slli_si128 (srcB, 8), 0xf0);
```